# The number of internal direct summands of a finitely generated abelian group

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a group. A normal subgroup  $H$ of $G$ is called an internal direct summand of $G$ if there exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$ so that $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{ 1\}$.

My question is that:

Is the number of internal direct summands of a finitely generated abelian group finite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true even for $G=\Bbb Z^2$. One can take $H=\left<(1,a)\right>$
for any integer $a$ (with $K=\left<(0,1)\right>$).

Comment: Or even any $H=\langle(a,b)\rangle$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$ ...