# Groups with the form $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ with finitely many retracts

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

A group $H$ is called a retract of a group $G$ if there exists homomorphisms $f:H\to G$ and $g:G\to H$ such that $gf=id_H$. When $G$ is abelian, a retract of $G$ is exactly a direct summand.

By [The number of internal direct summands of a finitely generated abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2671807/the-number-of-internal-direct-summands-of-a-finitely-generated-abelian-group) , $\mathbb{Z}^2$ (hence every finitely generated abelian group with rank greater than 1) have infinitely many direct summands. On the other hand, $\mathbb{Z}$ and finite abelian groups have clearly only finitely many retracts.

Does a finitely abelian group with the form $\mathbb{Z}\times G$, where $G$ is a (abelian) finite group, has only finitely many retracts $H$?

I'm  interested in retracts ***as subgroups $H \subset G$*** not "up to isomorhism".

Comment: As in the previous question, it is unclear from your post what exactly you mean by "finitely many retracts". My default interpretation would be that there are only finitely many group $H$ up to isomorphism with that property. But I think perhaps that is not what you mean, and that you are talking about the number of subgroups $H$ of $G$ with that property. Please edit the question and make that clear.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right. I've just edited my question as you said. Thank you very much for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{Z}\oplus G$ be the direct sum of subgroups $H$ and $K$.

Write each element of $\mathbb{Z}\oplus G$ as $(z,g)$.

Either $H$ or $K$ must be of the form $0\oplus J$, where $J$ is a subgroup of $G$.

The reason is that if $(m,g_1)\in H$ and $(n,g_2)\in K$ where $m\neq0$ and $n\neq0$, then $(mn|G|,e)=n|G|(m,g_1)=m|G|(n,g_2)\in H\cap K$.

So, let's suppose $H=0\oplus J$.

It follows that, writing $K\cap(0\oplus G)$ in the form $0\oplus F$, we have that $G$ is a direct product of $F$ and $J$.

$K$ must have at least one element of the form $(1,g)$. This is because, as I said, all elements of $H$ have the first coordinate as being $0$, and since $(1,e)=h+k$ for some $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, such a value of $k$ must have the first coordinate as being $1$.

Also, for such a choice of $g$, we have that $K$ is the direct product of $\langle (1,g)\rangle$ and $0\oplus F$.

If you've followed this argument, you'll see that $\mathbb{Z}\oplus G$ has only finitely many retracts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good answer. Does your argument still hold when $G$ is a nonabelian finite group?

Comment: @M.Ramana as for your second comment, yes you are right. As for your first comment, an almost identical argument does work for $G$ finite non-abelian

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.