# The number of retracts of $G\ltimes \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, retraction

I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486516/groups-with-the-form-mathbbz-times-g-with-finitely-many-retracts) that: does  $\mathbb{Z}\oplus G$, where $G$ is a finite abelian group, has only finitely many retracts? The answer was yes. Now I've tried to prove that the number of retracts of $\mathbb{Z}\rtimes G$ is also finite, where $G$ is a finite group. My try is based on the argument of [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4486516/groups-with-the-form-mathbbz-times-g-with-finitely-many-retracts). My question is that does the argument still holds for $\mathbb{Z}\ltimes G$?

**What I've tried:** The  ‎notation $+$‎ ‎is ‎used for the  group action ‎of ‎all ‎groups ‎throughout ‎this ‎argument.  ‎‎‎‎‎Let ‎$‎‎G$ ‎be a ‎finite ‎‎group ‎with ‎identity ‎‎element $e‎$‎ ‎and‎ ‎$‎‎H$ ‎be ‎an ‎arbitrary ‎retract ‎of ‎‎$G\ltimes ‎\mathbb{Z}‎‎$. ‎Then ‎there ‎exists a‎ ‎normal ‎subgroup ‎‎$N$ ‎of ‎‎$G\ltimes ‎\mathbb{Z}$ ‎such ‎that ‎‎$G\ltimes ‎\mathbb{Z}=H\ltimes N$.‎  Write each element of $G\ltimes ‎\mathbb{Z}$ as $(g,z)$. We show that either $H$ or $N$ must be of the form $J \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}‎$, where $J$ is a subgroup of $G$. In fact, if  $(g_1,m)\in H$ and $(g_2,n)\in N$ where $m\neq0$ and $n\neq0$, then $(e,mn|G|)=n|G|(g_1,m)=m|G|(g_2,n)\in H\cap N$ which is a contradiction.‎

‎
First, let's suppose $H=J \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}$. ‎‎‎‎Writing $N\cap(‎G\ltimes \{ 0\})$ in the form $F \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}$, we have that $G$ is the semidirect product of  $F$ and $J$, ‎i.e. ‎‎$G=J\ltimes F‎‎‎‎$.‎

‎
Now, we assume that ‎$‎‎N=J \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}$.‎  Since all elements of $N$ have the second coordinate as being $0$, and since $(e,1)=h+n$ for some $h\in H$ and $n\in N$, such a value of $h$ must have the second coordinate as being $1$. Thus  $H$ must have at least one element of the form $(g,1)$. Also, for such a choice of $g$, we have that $H$ is the semidirect product of $\langle (g,1)\rangle$ and $F' \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}$, where ‎$F' \ltimes‎ \{ 0\}=H\cap(‎G\ltimes \{ 0\})‎‎$.‎ Hence,  $G\ltimes ‎\mathbb{Z}$ has only finitely many retracts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that a retract of $G$ I mean a subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that there exists a normal subgroup $N$ with $G=N\rtimes H$.

If $G$ is infinite dihedral, then every subgroup of order 2 is a retract. And there are infinitely many. However, there are only two conjugacy classes.

In general, let $G$ be virtually cyclic. Then its finite subgroups have bounded order. So its infinite retracts have finite bounded index. Since there are finitely many subgroups of given index, we deduce there are finitely many retracts of finite index (this actually applies in every finitely generated group with a maximal finite subgroup "finite radical").

In a virtually cyclic group, infinite index subgroups are finite. So we have to count finite retracts.

By a result of Wall, $G$ is either finite-by-cyclic or finite-by-dihedral. If $G$ is finite-by-cyclic, then it has finitely many finite subgroups.

Now suppose that $G$ is finite-by-dihedral. Let $W$ be its finite radical. Then maximal finite subgroups of $G$ have index 2 over $W$, and there are two conjugacy classes of such subgroups, and each has finitely many subgroups. Hence there are finitely many retracts up to conjugacy (but possibly infinitely many).

Comment: Thanks very much for your great explanation. By what you said, the infinite dihedral group $D_{\infty}$ has infinitely many retracts. Now by the fact that $D_{\infty}= \mathbb{Z}\rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$, we conclude that my argument in "what I've tried" is wrong. Right?

Comment: Therefore, $\mathbb{Z} \rtimes G$ may have infinitely many retracts. But what about $G\ltimes \mathbb{Z}$? Why my argument is wrong?

Comment: @M.Ramana you should indeed choose $C_2\ltimes\mathbf{Z}$ with the nontrivial action and check the argument line-by-line. At least you know that you get other retracts by taking $\mathbf{Z}$-conjugates of $C_2$.

Comment: But as I wrote, $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes W$ for $W$ finite has finitely many retracts.

Comment: Yes, got it. I'll do it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I was wondering if you could tell me is my argument right for Z⋉G when G is finite?

Comment: @M.Ramana it's already written in the post (finite-by-cyclic case)...

Comment: By your words, we divide all retracts of a finite-by-cylclic group into two classes: finite retracts, and infinite ones.  Since $G$ has finitely many finite subgroups, so the first class has finitely many elements. But I don't understand these facts "Then its finite subgroups have bounded order. So its infinite retracts have finite bounded index. Since there are finitely many subgroups of given index, we deduce there are finitely many retracts of finite index". Could you please explain a little more about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. 1) I divide cyclic-by-finite groups into finite-by-cyclic and finite-by-dihedral groups (regardless of considering retracts). In the first case $G$ has finitely many finite subgroups, we are done. In the second case, $G$ has infinitely many finite subgroups but finitely up to conjugacy.

Comment: Yes, got it. I appreciate that. Dear @YCor , can I ask two more questions? I really want to figure it out. Why the finite subgroups of a virtually cyclic group have bounded order? And how can we conclude that its infinite retracts have finite bounded index?